# How to add a Ribbon to a form application

Tags: c#, ribbon

I am using C#, and VS2013. I want to create a ribbon in a new blank form.

The documentation I am using is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534(v=vs.110).aspx

I downloaded and installed:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877, but I still don't see any ribbon components in my toolbox even after installing.

What am I doing wrong? or how do I build a Ribbon?

Comment: did u figure it out I have same problem?

Answer (score -1):

first add a references to `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon` dll from your wpf 4.5 project.

then you'll be able tu write in your xaml code like this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Ribbon>
            <!-- other inner controls goes here -->           
        </Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This simple does not answer the question. the question is they are not showing in toolbox.